# Deploying to heroku with git keeps getting rejected due to fast-forwards

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

I keep getting the following fail with heroku + git...

```
$ heroku jammit:deploy --app XXXXXXXXXXX
===== Compiling assets...[OK]
===== Commiting assets...[OK]
===== Done...
===== Deploying assets for xxxxx-staging to heroku...
To git@heroku.com:XXXXXXXX.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:xxx-staging.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
[FAIL]
===== Done...
===== Deleting compiled assets...[OK]
===== Commiting deleted assets...[OK]
===== Done...
$ git pull
Already up-to-date.
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or should be doing differently to allow for pushing without having to force a push?

Thanks

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Just force the commit every time you push and it will push it even if there are fast-forward commits.  We do this in our development Heroku server all the time since we're all pushing different commits (some further behind than others).

```
git push -f git@heroku.com:picasso-staging.git
```

I don't use jammit for deploying, but you could probably get away with force pushing first and then running the jammit task second.  Or check and see if jammit supports a force push flag of some sort.

Answer (score 8):

```
git push -f REMOTE BRANCH:master #or just master
```

Force it! Replace REMOTE with your heroku remote name (`git remote -v` to view all remotes). Replace BRANCH with the branch you want to push or just put "master" for the master branch.

Comment: I think you mean "git remote -v" to view all remotes.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that changes have already been pushed and your commit is behind those newer pushes. I'm going to assume you have a master branch and your feature branch still, let's say it's called `my_feature`. You can do this and be okay:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my_feature
git rebase master
    (you may have to fix some conflicts here, if any are found)
git checkout master
git merge my_feature
git push heroku
```

You should remember to run any tests you have to make sure everything's good still.

Comment: Thanks for this but right now since we're pre=launch, it's all on the master branch. Suggestions?

Comment: $ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.

Comment: origin/master is not the same as master. origin/master is a remote branch that when you just do "git pull" it pulls the changes in to, and then merges them in to master ("git fetch" just pulls the changes in to origin/master and then you can merge manually). So yea, your master branch is ahead of what was last pulled down, so go ahead and `git pull`. You'll probably have some conflicts and after if it's all good just push then! No need to rebase then if you're already on your local master.

Comment: thanks but git pull continues to say everything is up to date just like mentioned above in the question

Comment: Do you have a GUI for git, like gitk? If not you can download one. That will be better, because you can see all the commits to your repository and see where your local master is, where your origin/master is, and see what the newest commit is on your project.

Comment: Well github doesn't show it in the same way that gitk or GitGui (Windows) will, because they will show you where your remote branches sit as well. But anyways, do a "git log" on your master and you will see what commits you have, and compare that to github. github should have commits you don't have, I believe.

Comment: Thanks it's all in sync. My guess is heroku is out of sync. Is there a way to see what git commit is running on heroku?

Comment: @MrDanA let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2026/discussion-between-anapprentice-and-mrdana)